# Writing on a CSV in Applescript (Using terminal shell)

Tags: shell, csv, awk, applescript

Just trying to write onto an CSV file that I choose from a dialog box. For some reason, this isn't working. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

```
set theFile to (choose file)
do shell script "awk -F, '$1 ~ /Line 2/{$22=\"hello\"} 1'  & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile & > /tmp/a"
```

EDIT:
I just want to write on a chosen CSV on a particular row/column (in this case row 2, column 22). At the moment it's not throwing any error but not writing on the chosen CSV either, displaying the output "" –

Comment: what is the desired behavior and what is going wrong?

Comment: I just want to write on a chosen CSV on a particular row/column (in this case row 2, column 22). At the moment it's not throwing any error but not writing on the chosen CSV either, displaying the output ""

Comment: please edit the question to include this. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command write the output of the **awk** command to a file named "**a**" in the "**tmp**" folder (this folder is hidden), so the output of the `do shell script` is ""

Your command edit lines where the content of the first field is equal to "**Line 2**".

- To edit the second line, use `NR==2`

  To edit line 1 through 5, use `NR<6`

  To edit line 10 through 15, use `NR>9 && NR<16`

Standard **awk** on **OS X** cannot edit the file in place, so you must write the output to a temporary file and use the `mv` command to overwrite the original file,  but its possible with **GNU awk 4.1.0...** --> `gawk -i inplace`

---

To edit the second line of some file (the line ending in the CSV file must be a line feed), use this:

```
set theFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose file)
set tempFile to theFile & ".tmp123"
do shell script "awk -F, 'NR==2{$22=\"hello\";}1' OFS=, " & theFile & " >" & tempFile & "&& mv -f " & tempFile & " " & theFile
```

---

if the line ending in the CSV file is a carriage return, use this:

```
do shell script "awk -F, 'NR==2{$22=\"hello\";}1' RS='\\r' ORS='\\r' OFS=, " & theFile & " >" & tempFile & "&& mv -f " & tempFile & " " & theFile
```

---

**Update**

Here's an example how to put an AppleScript variable (**m**) into the command.

```
set m to 6 -- a number
do shell script "awk -F, 'NR<" & m & "{$22=\"hello\";}1' RS='\\r' ORS='\\r' OFS=, " & theFile & " >" & tempFile & "&& mv -f " & tempFile & " " & theFile
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the carriage return works perfectly

Comment: One last thing, is it possible to do NR<m where m is a variable calculated on run-time. If so who would I have to do to m so that it is recognized as a variable

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of `quoted form` is wrong here. You have to interrupt the AppleScript string and add it between your string parts. Try this:

```
set theFile to (choose file)
do shell script "awk -F, '$1 ~ /Line 2/{$22=\"hello\"} 1' " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile & " > /tmp/a"
```

If the rest of your shell command is fine, it should fix it...

Have fun, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still doesn't work. It's not throwing any error but just not writing on the CSV either. Just want to write on the line 2, column 22 on the particular file chosen.

Comment: That may be an `awk` problem, which I am not familiar with. But the `quoted form` answer is helpful, too :)

Answer (score 0):

If your main intention is really to run a `bash`+`awk` script, you can do things the other way around...

Instead of starting in Applescript and trying to run a shell and `awk`, you could start in the shell and invoke Applescript to choose a file and then carry on in the shell and run `awk`.

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$( osascript -e 'set theFile to (POSIX path of (choose file))' )
awk '1' "$file"
```

So, you get a `bash` script that invokes Applescript, rather than an Applescript that invokes `bash`.

Note that `1` is just true in an `awk` script, so `awk` will just do its default thing, which is print the current line - obviously you would put your own `awk` commands in there.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear, this was a function of a longer script, but I'm sure this would've worked too :)